# Sudden spike in bandwidth

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

For the past three days there has been sudden spike in bandwidth. Upon analyzing a specific IP address is constantly doing catalog search. Please see attachment. What is the best way to block this bandwidth consumption. I already have Disallow: /catalogsearch/ in robots.txt. Do I ask the hosting provider to block the IP?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009248/limit-bandwidth-per-apache-virtual-host for options to throttle bandwidth at the Apache level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody is using a server hosted on a server farm in San Antonio, Texas to scrape your website or some such. Given its Magento, it may also be a Denial of Service attack by resource loading.

```
IP Address    104.130.207.148
Country Code  US
Country Name  United States
Region Name   Texas
City Name     San Antonio
ISP           Cloud Servers
Domain Name   cloud4server.net
Usage Type    Data Center/Web Hosting/Transit
```

Block the IP address in .htaccess or via firewall rule, robots.txt only works for legitimate web indexers, which this isn't.

Comment: Shouldn't Disallow: /catalogsearch/ in robots.txt work?

Comment: @EthnicCode only if it is a bot that "wants to play nice". If robots.txt would help for all others bot attacks it would be too easy :D

Comment: Not at all. Attackers use robots.txt to decide what's important to attack. Web indexers use it as a courtesy to let you tell them what to leave alone.

Answer (score 0):

blocking manually just this IP address wont help you much, look at the time frame, 3 requests per second, correct way is to configure apache throttling and limiting multiple requests from the same ip/source.

also limiting catalog search is good start.
**using cache is much better than blocking.**

firewall must be configured properly to block this kind of attack.

Comment: how to limit catalog search?

Comment: you have to use cache or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second